# Opencart 3. Как вывести производителя в модулях на главной странице?

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

OpenCart v.3.0.2.0

Под описанием товара `{{ product.description }}` вывести `{{ manufacturer }}` внутри модуля например `latest.php`

В шаблоне предельно просто, а контроллеру что-то не нравится.

Answer (score 0):

Решил.
добавить {{ product.manufacturer }} в шаблоне модуля latest.twig
в контроллере latest.php добавить след.

```html
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($result['product_id']);
        
        $data['products'][] = array(
          'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
          'thumb'       => $image,
          'name'        => $result['name'],
          'description' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
          'price'       => $price,
          'special'     => $special,
          'tax'         => $tax,
          'rating'      => $rating,
          'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id']),
          'manufacturer'=> $product_info['manufacturer']
        );
```